# introductory calculus - Help me find a function with a few properties

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I was asked to find a function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that:

1) $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

2) $f$ has directional derivatives at $(0,0)$ (does this mean $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$?)

3) There is such a vector $v \in \mathbb R^2$, $|v|=1$ such that the directional derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$ in the direction $v$ is not bound. it is extremely large. In other words, there has to be a normalized vector $v$ such that the standard inner product of the gradient of $f$ at $(0,0)$ and $v$ is extremely large.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can try to find a function which is defined by cases. If I remember well, $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, \text{if} \hspace{2pt}y = x^2 \\0, \text{if else} \end{cases}$$ may work... but you can verify yourself, for good practice.

2) Having all directional derivatives does NOT mean that it's differentiable at the given point, you would have to check the incremental limit.

3) Have you tried to actually get a $\frac{\vec{v}}{\vert\vert v \vert \vert} = \left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}, \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\right)$ and do the calculation? May be easier than you think, given the right function.